# CSS - hover doesn't work

Tags: css, hover

I have these css code:

```
    .tabs_inactive {
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border-bottom: #cccccc;
    }

    .tabs_inactive:hover {
        background-color: #ff8000;
        border-color: #ff8000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /*this does not work*/
    .tabs_inactive:hover a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .tabs_active {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .tabs_active:hover{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .tabs_active:hover a {
        cursor: default;
    }
```

The last one (`.tab_active:hover a`) is working perfectly in my webpage, but the third block is not. I can not figure out why this happened.
Could somebody explain me why the third block doesn't work?
Thanks!

---

UPDATE 1:
Here is the relative JavaScript code:

```
//add class "tabs_inactive" to the original tabs option.
$( "#tabs ul li" ).addClass("tabs_inactive");

//default: set the first tab as the active one.
$( "#tabs ul li" ).first().toggleClass("tabs_active");

//to make sure the style sheet will be changed when click on the inside <a> tag
$( "#tabs ul li a" ).live( "click", function () {
    //close other tabs
    $( this ).parents("ul").children("li").each( function (){
        if( $(this).hasClass("tabs_active")){
            $(this).removeClass("tabs_active");
        }
    });
    $( this ).parent().toggleClass("tabs_active");
    return false;
});
//change the class to "tabs_active" when the tab is clicked
$( "#tabs ul li" ).live( "click", function () {
    //close other tab
    $( this ).parent().children("li").each( function (){
        if( $(this).hasClass("tabs_active")){
            $(this).removeClass("tabs_active");
        }
    });
    $( this ).toggleClass("tabs_active");
});
```

And also HTML code:

```
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage">HOME</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#option1">option1</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="homepage">
                <p>
                    HOME:
                    Here is the home page
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="option1">
                <p>
                    Option1:
                    Here is the tag page 1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So, yes, I am trying to implement a tab menu, and this is a practice so I don't want to use the original JqueryUI function. Dose somebody know that what is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML you are marking up, it is tough to really determine what may or may not be going on, but you can try adding `display: block` to the elements that are not triggering the hover event.

Comment: hard to tell without more info. You may be able to just !important override it. I would guess another rule is overriding it and you may have not given the selector a high enough priority.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your html (that you really should let us see so we can actually help you)? I only say this because in your question, your CSS says `.tabs_active:hover a` whereas in your actual question, you say `The last one (.tab_active:hover a)`. As silly as it is, typos like this aren't uncommon and often go amiss at first. But like the other three comments say, we need to see the HTML otherwise you can't really be guaranteed a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it's not a typo or something else, I just make a mistake that I give a font color style to the `#tab ul li a` before, which is using the id selector, and that make the the function `toggleClass` doesn't work at all. I convert that tag from id to class then every thing works fine. thanks all, That's my bad.